Extract the Max Contour value of the Parts [TCL scipt integration in Hyperview]
I am currently working on customizing a macro in order to display the “Query” of the following results (Component ID, Component name, Contour (stress/strain)). The ultimate goal is to export these results into a text file named "table.txt" using TCL script as depicted in the attached image.

I have attached the script, While I have successfully managed to print the  Component ID and Component name but not the Contour values (maximum and ID).
I am using HyperView 2021.2 version and Radioss solver.

Can anyone help me, please ? I can provide more info if necessary.
Also is there any other method where I can extract the Maximum Stress/strain value per component using TCL script ? (Function is very similar to Interactive "Query" table in Hyperview, but I want to perform that operation couple of times on several Hyperview pages/windows.
I did contact the Altair support for the same but there is no satifactory solution on my problem (by using TCL function), Although they suggested using an interactive "Query" table in Hyperview and export results. I am looking a way to automize this step.
Thanks in advance
TCL Code:
    mod GetQueryCtrlHandle query1
    mod GetSelectionSetHandle mySetName [mod  AddSelectionSet  component]
    mySetName Add all
    res SetCurrentSimulation 1

    query1 SetDataSourceProperty result datatype Stress
    query1 SetDataSourceProperty result shelllayer Max
    query1 SetQuery "component.id component.name contour.value result.value"
    query1 SetSelectionSet 1
    
    query1 WriteData {C:/Desktop/table.txt};
    anim Draw


if you have more then one page and more windows, first you need to get number of pages and windows and iterate through them one by one.
Check my below code, it will run for active window and will store queried values in one list for components of active window.
    set ui [expr rand()]
    hwi GetActiveClientHandle my_client$ui
    my_client$ui GetModelHandle my_model$ui [my_client$ui GetActiveModel]
    my_client$ui ReleaseHandle

    set set_id [my_model$ui AddSelectionSet part]       
    my_model$ui GetSelectionSetHandle my_set$ui $set_id
    my_set$ui Add all;
                            
    # set selection set inside the query ctrl
    my_model$ui GetQueryCtrlHandle my_query$ui
    my_query$ui SetSelectionSet [ my_set$ui GetID ]
    my_model$ui RemoveSelectionSet [my_set$ui GetID]
                            
    # create request
    my_query$ui SetQuery "component.id component.name contour.max"
    #Iterate through all visbile components 
    my_query$ui GetIteratorHandle my_iterator$ui
    my_iterator$ui First
    while { [my_iterator$ui Valid] == "true" } {
        lappend tmpCompList [my_iterator$ui GetDataList]
    my_iterator$ui Next }

    set contourdetails ""
    for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $tmpCompList]} {incr i} {
        set tmpstr [lindex $tmpCompList $i]
        lassign [split $tmpstr " "] comp_id comp_name max_contour
        if {$max_contour > 0} {
            set contourdetails "$comp_id~$comp_name~$max_contour"
        }
        
    }

